# The curious case of the Ace of Spades (creating array of objects in python3)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, self

I am trying to create an array (deck) of objects (cards). To achieve this I am using the Card.construct() method on the Deck.card object inide the Deck.construct() method. I am able to succesfully create an array (Deck.cards) of card objects, the trouble is all of those are Aces of Spades, 52 of them. This is where the array gets created:

```
def construct(self):
        for value in self.card.values:
            for suit in self.card.suits:
                self.card.construct(value, suit)
                self.card.showNice()
                self.cards.append(self.card)
```

Different kinds of cards are being printed correctly right before the assignment but for some reason only the Ace of Spades seems to be appended to the array. I really don't get why is this happening.

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = ''
        self.values = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
        self.suit = ''
        self.suits = ['♥', '♦', '♣', '♠']
        self.valit = (self.value, self.suit)

    def construct(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        self.valit = (value, suit)

    def random(self):
        self.valit = (random.choice(self.values), random.choice(self.suits))

    def show(self):
        print(self.valit, end='')

    def showNice(self):
        print(self.value, self.suit, ' ', sep='', end='')

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.card = Card()
        self.cards = []

    def construct(self):
        for value in self.card.values:
            for suit in self.card.suits:
                self.card.construct(value, suit)
                self.cards.append(self.card)

    def shuffleUp(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def show(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.show()
        print('\n')

    def showNice(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.showNice()
        print('\n')
```

...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from environment.environment import *

class shuffleUpAndDeal():
    deck = Deck()
    deck.construct()
    deck.shuffleUp()
    deck.showNice()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    shuffleUpAndDeal()
```

I am new to the whole idea of objects, classes, methods etc. so more than likely I am not optimising the code in a correct way, any suggestions much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should almost definitely get rid of the `value`, `suite` and `valit` fields of the class. Don't store arbitrary information as instance variables like that. Return a card from `construct`, then append the returned card to `cards`. When possible, pass information explicitly to functions, and return information from them; don't rely on the background state of the object. That probably isn't your problem, but your code is very confusing to read. Fixing that may clear things up.

Comment: You create EXACTLY ONE ``Card`` object in your entire program, in ``Deck.__init__()``.  You then proceed to set that one card to each combination of value and suit, sequentially.

Comment: Carcigenicate point taken, jasonharper excuse me for not getting the terminology right

Comment: And as a hint (since I don't have a computer to debug it, and that would be offtopic anyways), note how the Spade is the last symbol in the list, as is the Ace. That suggests you're looping somewhere but only keeping the last result. Until you fix storing everything as instance members in the object though, this will be unnecessarily complicated to debug.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes I gathered that much, what bugs me is how the card is being printed correctly right before the assignment, yet it becomes something else after the assignment takes place. I am getting an array of instances of 'card' inside the array though, its just the values are surprisingly incorrect. In a moment of maddening brilliance I have fixed this issue yesterday (and at that moment I knew exactly what was wrong) only to rebuild it completely and break it again. Now I'm completely stuck. For me this should work, but it doesn't (isn't that always the case though?).

Comment: @soocki I know you'd probably rather just fix this then move on, but I suggest you try fixing the functions. It's amazing how often you'll reformat some broken code, and everything becomes clearer. I'm having issues debugging this in my head since the effect of every function is dependant on whatever else has been called on the object prior. Functions should ideally be isolated chunks of code that take some explicit input, and produce an explicit output. That way, each function can be tested individually; and that's a huge win.

Comment: @Carcigenicate my attitude is the opposite of 'moving on and forgetting', would prefer to learn and gain from this as much as possible instead. The thing is I have no idea how to rebuild this in a 'proper' way since I don't know what the proper way is. I never done it any other way, in fact never ever done it before so all this is the effect of Great Improvisation With Python Classes/Functions. Sorry if it's confusing, will try and figure out how to make it better, for now I'm afraid that's what we are stuck with. Thanks for taking interest man.

Comment: @soocki Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but I haven't written Python in over a year. I noticed you haven't used `return` anywhere. Do you know what it does/how to use it? Explicitly returning results instead of mutating/reassigning `self.` variables would be a good first step. Good luck with your debugging.

Comment: If you aren't familiar with returning, this is a great read: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/51c0e35d7c82caace80008b1

Comment: @Carcigenicate yeah, I know about 'return' ;) I just thought I could do without it and create a virtual 'deck' of 'cards' that I could 'shuffle' and 'deal' etc. and the 'self' thing looked like a good tool to achieve this. This is confusing this Ace of Spades, need to wait for another 'Eureka!' moment so it seems.

Comment: @soocki Go take a walk if you've been staring at it for awhile. I hope you see the light; so to speak. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you're reusing the same instance of `Card` over and over again, and changing it after it's already been added to the list. You've added references to the same card to the list 52 times, and changed the same card 52 times. That's why it ends up on the last combination.

Note this part:

```
def construct(self):
    for value in self.card.values:
        for suit in self.card.suits:
            self.card.construct(value, suit)
            self.cards.append(self.card)

    print(self.cards) # I added this line
```

This is what the `print` prints:

```
[<__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0377DB10>]
```

See the `0x0377DB10` bit? That's the address of the object. Note how they're all the same! Every time you call `self.card.construct(value, suit)`, you're just changing that single instance, including all the references to it that are already in `self.cards`.

If you ran your test, **then** changed `deck.card.suit`, **then** ran the test again, you'd see that all the cards had simultaneously changed.

Create a new card every time so you're not constantly overwriting the same instance.

Here's a modified version that works. Note how I create a new card every time:

```
def construct(self):
    for value in self.card.values:
        for suit in self.card.suits:
            card = Card()
            card.construct(value, suit)

            self.cards.append(card)

    print(self.cards)
```

This is what the new version prints:

```
[<__main__.Card object at 0x0376DB90>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DBB0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DBD0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DBF0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DC10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DC30>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DC50>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DC70>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DC90>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DCB0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DCD0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DCF0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DD10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DD30>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DD50>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DD70>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DD90>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DDB0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DDD0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DDF0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DE10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DE30>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DE50>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DE70>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DE90>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DEB0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DED0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DEF0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DF10>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DF30>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DF50>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DF70>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DF90>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DFB0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DFD0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0376DFF0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x03775030>, <__main__.Card object at 0x03775050>, <__main__.Card object at 0x03775070>, <__main__.Card object at 0x03775090>, <__main__.Card object at 0x037750B0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x037750D0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x037750F0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x03775110>, <__main__.Card object at 0x03775130>, <__main__.Card object at 0x03775150>, <__main__.Card object at 0x03775170>, <__main__.Card object at 0x03775190>, <__main__.Card object at 0x037751B0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x037751D0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x037751F0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x03775210>]
```

Note how all the addresses are different! They're all different cards now.

When I run your test, I get:

```
2♥ K♥ 3♥ J♥ 6♥ 5♣ 7♣ 7♦ 8♣ 5♦ 3♣ Q♥ 10♣ 9♣ 9♥ A♦ 8♥ 9♠ 6♠ A♠ K♣ K♠ J♦ 2♦ 7♥ 10♠ 6♦ 6♣ 4♠ 5♠ K♦ 3♦ 4♥ 9♦ Q♠ 7♠ A♣ 4♣ 10♦ A♥ Q♦ 4♦ 5♥ J♣ 8♠ 3♠ J♠ Q♣ 8♦ 10♥ 2♣ 2♠
```

I'd like to point out though that the `construct` method is unnecessary . It's doing the job the `Card` constructor should be doing, but in far less intuitive way. The point of the constructor is to `construct`. Think about what the state of the card would be if you forgot to call `construct` on it. It's impossible to forget if you just use the constructor.

Comment: well I'll be damned. Thanks a lot for the effort taking this on. Now when you explained it it makes so much sense. Thanks for extensive  explanation too, much appreciated. I'll work on the constructor and as you suggested I'll put all the relevant bits in the __init__ section where it belongs. The fact the constructor constructs makes a lot of sense too! Take care man!